# Summing variable values across a row that are unique to that row

Tags: r

I have a dataset the captures monthly enrollment in insurance (M1 to M5). I also have variables that capture a month of diagnosis (T1) and a month of death (T2). I want to determine whether there was continuous enrollment in the insurance plan in the month of diagnosis through the month of death. An example dataframme is below:

```
    r1 <- c(1,3,4,0,0,1,1,0)
    r2 <- c(2,3,5,0,0,1,0,0)
    r3 <- c(3,1,4,1,1,1,1,0)

    df <- as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2,r3))

    colnames(df) <- c("ID", "T1", "T2", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5")
```

I want code that takes the sum of the values for the variables from the diagnosis enrollment month variable (M#) to the death enrollment month variable (M#) so that I have a dataframe that looks like below.

```
    df$sum <- c(2,1,4)
    df
```

I have tried many things but I just can't come up with the logic to perform this task. For example, I changed the values of T1 and T2 to the variable names that are needed to do the sum as below and then tried to think of an dplyr if_else strategy where I group by ID and then create a new sum variable but I don't know how to select the variables that are needed based on the values of T1 and T2.

```
    r1 <- c(1,"M3","M4",0,0,1,1,0)
    r2 <- c(2,"M3","M5",0,0,1,0,0)
    r3 <- c(3,"M1","M4",1,1,1,1,0)

    df <- as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2,r3))

    colnames(df) <- c("ID", "T1", "T2", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5")
    df
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(total = rowSums(pick(starts_with("M"))[, T1:T2])) |>
  ungroup()
```

**How it works**

The operation you want to perform is by each row, so having a `rowwise` data frame is important here. `pick` pulls *all* the month variables. Those month columns are then subset by position using `T1:T2`, which is unique for each row.

For example, the expression `pick(starts_with("M"))[, T1:T2])` will return:

```
# for the first row
     M3    M4
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1

# for the second row
     M3    M4    M5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0
.
.
.
```

We can then simply `rowSums` these data frames to get the total you requested during the range.

**Output**

```
     ID    T1    T2    M1    M2    M3    M4    M5 total
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     4     0     0     1     1     0     2
2     2     3     5     0     0     1     0     0     1
3     3     1     4     1     1     1     1     0     4
```

---

You are trying to look at consecutive months during a range, when the range varies across `ID`. You could standardize across rows by creating a proportion of months with coverage during the range, like so:

```
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(coverage = rowSums(pick(starts_with("M"))[, T1:T2]) / length(T1:T2)) |>
  ungroup()

     ID    T1    T2    M1    M2    M3    M4    M5 coverage
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1     3     4     0     0     1     1     0    1    
2     2     3     5     0     0     1     0     0    0.333
3     3     1     4     1     1     1     1     0    1
```

Here you can more readily see `ID` 1 and 3 had 100% coverage during this period, while `ID` 2 did not (only 33.3% of the time).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think this will work. You are a wizard!